# Does work-sharing mechanism (in OpenMP) transmits tasks between threads WHILE threads are executing?

Tags: gcc, openmp

I must to learn `OpenMP` sources on `gcc`. I have read documentations of `OpenMP` (3.0 and 4.0). As I know, OpenMP used `work-sharing` mechanism. As I understand `work-sharing` mechanism transmits tasks between threads **while** threads are running. Or does distribution of data between threads is executing before executing these threads?

Comment: Learning to [implement the work-sharing yourself can teach you a lot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30591616/2542702).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using OpenMP with **tasks**, the tasks are stored in one or more task queues. If a thread finds itself idle, it will snoop tasks from a neighboring queue. This is internal to `libgomp`.

If you use OpenMP **parallel for** with a static schedule, no task snooping will take place.

If you use OpenMP **parallel for** with a dynamic schedule, threads in team will divide the work dynamically, so idle threads will take tasks from the rest of the team.

In general, when threads need to communicate at run-time, cycles are spent away from processing.

Answer (score 3):

Complementing @klaas-van-gend answer: in order for a `libgomp` thread to start stealing *tasks* it needs to be idle *AND* not be in any active `taskwait` construct (explicit or implicit).

For example, think of a binary tree representing a task graph. If the thread that created the root node is not fast enough to start running one of its two children, it will be idle until the execution of its child tasks is finished.

This behavior is observed in GCC 9.1.

If we run [this code](https://pastebin.com/QFx5V1bK) with `libgomp` we can observe the behavior thanks to graphviz graph generated. Colors and numbers inside parenthesis represent a core/thread. The number outsid parenthesis indicates the computational weight of task, and the number on edges is the time when task started to run. 
[image: libgomp task tree]
As we can see, the core 1 (blue) stayed idle until the end of its `taskwait` construct. Core 0 (white) only stealed task 6 after the end of the `taskwait` created by task 4. Same for core 3 (green) and task 12.

However, if we run this code with Clang/LLVM and `libomp` implementation, we have a fully work-stealing algorithm. No core is idle at any time. This behavior is observed on Clang 8 :)
[image: libomp task tree]