# Using OpenMP to parallelize a for loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I'm new to OpenMP. When I parallelize a `for` loop using

```
  #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
  for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    //some parallelizable code
  }
```

Is it guaranteed that every thread takes one and only one value of `i`? How is the loop work divided among the threads in general when `num_threads` is not equal to or does not evenly divide the total number of times of the for loop? Is there a command I can use to specify that each thread takes only one value of `i`, or the number of values of `i` each thread takes?

Comment: Hi, look at the schedule kw, https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x5aw0hdf(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: As Microsoft supports only OpenMP 2.0, most other OpenMP implementations will have additional useful options.

Comment: I find it constructive to [implement the scheduling yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30591616/2542702).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The work division in a loop construct is decided by the *schedule*. If no `schedule` clause is present, the *def-sched-var* schedule is used, which is implementation defined.

You could use `schedule (static, 1)`, which in your case guarantees that each thread will get exactly one value.

I highly recommend to take a look at the [OpenMP specification](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/openmp-4.5.pdf), Table 2.5 and 2.7.1.1.

There may be legitimate reasons for making this kind of assumptions, but in general the correctness of your loop code should not depend on this. Primarily I would treat this as a performance-hint.

Depending on your use-case you may want to consider tasks or just parallel constructs. If you rely such details for loops, make sure it is well specified in the standard, and not *just works* in your particular implementation.

Comment: Default schedule is expected to use maximum chunk sizes.

Comment: Thanks. I found a [link](http://cs.umw.edu/~finlayson/class/fall16/cpsc425/notes/12-scheduling.html) that gives me a code to check the schedule. The default scheduler should be static and will apportion at compile time the number of `i` values to the threads as evenly as possible. This is ensuring.

Comment: Such experiments are great to learn how stuff works. But make sure that assumptions in your portable, future-proof code are based only on the standard.